# OpenCL Big Number Multiplication

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I was complanining about `OpenCL` too much these days. I am looking on big number multiply functions on there (not a matrix multiply) and made something works nice but I have failures also. I have several questions like this;

- First of all, what is the best multiply algorithm for to do two integer arrays(represents a big number like 100000 digits). I do like school grade system a little bit and matrix multiplication(of addition cross lines). I have checked Karatsuba and ToomCook but they are recursive I see and `OpenCL` inside doesn't allow this. Do I did true way or is there something so easy?
- I have lookin for running kernel multiple times because my gpu doesn't work true when excessing 512 digits on. That looklike a `local_work_size` problem but when I try global(1024) and local(512) inputs on NDKernel, it doesn't work too.(Invalid worksize error) I have two GPU on my mac which is Iris pro and R9M370X. AMD one is quite efficient now but excess situations still a problem.
- Using barrier(GLOBAL) didn't work after 512 digits also. I think there isn't any good idea except this. If i use 2048 global and 256 local size, kernel should work 8 workgroup with 256 local size I guess. I tried on local barrier and global barrier(which is works) but none of worked. After 512 digits ( or 1024 digits without shifting - just addition of cross lines of matrix-) it gives different values.
- Last one is should I divide the long array into little arrays and work them heterogenous kernels. I mean in a for loop, giving arguments as a little pieces.

I send a two arrays of integers (`int* A` and `int* B`) to kernel which is downside.

I hope I explained my situation. Thanks for any help.

```
kernel void multiply(global int* A,
                 const int M,
                 global int* B,
                 const int N,
                 global int* C) {
    //const int row = get_local_id(0); // Row ID of C (0..M)
    const int globalRow = get_global_id(0);
    uint globalCol;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<M+N+1;i++) {
        C[i]=0;
    }

    for (globalCol=0; globalCol<N; globalCol++) {
        int val=A[globalRow]*B[globalCol];
        C[globalCol + globalRow +1]+=val/10;
        //barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        C[globalCol + globalRow]+=val%10;
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); 

        C[globalCol+1+globalRow]+=val/10;

    }

    int flag=1;
    while (flag) {
        flag=0;
        for (i=M+N-1   ; i>=0 ; i--) {
            if (C[i]>9) {
                barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

                C[i+1]+=C[i]/10;
                barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

                C[i]=C[i]%10;
                //barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(barriers are I tried which work)

Comment: As for the first question, the answer depends on the threshold at which asymptotically 'faster' algorithms pay off. If the integers are large enough, [FFT algorithms](https://gmplib.org/manual/Multiplication-Algorithms.html) will be best. A google search reveals quite a few results for GPGPU implementations.

Comment: @BrettHale threshold is thousands digits anyway, FFT looks fine, actually i was looking this now. Thanks.

Comment: Please understand that OpenCL only has workgroup synchronization, not global synchronization. Some workgroups are going to completely finish before others even get started. There is no mechanism for global synchronization except to enqueue multiple kernels.